# A case about javascript closure and anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Let see code first

```
var name = "The Window"; 
var object = { 
  name : "My Object", 
  getNameFunc : function(){ 
    return function(){ 
      return this.name; 
    }; 
   } 
}; 

alert(object.getNameFunc()());
```

the result is `"The Window"`;
I want to know what happend in every step.
I think `this` is point to the object which call this function; right?
But why in this case `this` is `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function invocation doesn't take place from the context of an object, but rather from the function returned from the first invocation.

Because there's no object context, the `this` value becomes the default `window` just like any other function.

```
 //   v-----------------v------function has context
alert(object.getNameFunc()());
            // -----------^----second function was returned from the first
            //                   and invoked so there's no object context
```

If we instead assigned the returned function to `object`, then invoked it from that context, `this` would then be a reference to `object`.

```
obj.foo = object.getNameFunc();
obj.foo();  // "My Object"
```

Same exact function, but now it's being invoked from as a property of `object`, which implicitly sets its `this` value to `object`.

---

The rules of `this` are really pretty simple and easy to understand, but may not be what you'd expect at first.

The `this` value is very dynamic, and is based entirely on *how* a function is invoked.

```
foo();            // 'this' is 'window'

object.foo();     // 'this' is 'object'

foo.call(object); // 'this' is 'object'
foo.apply(object);// 'this' is 'object'

var bar = foo.bind(object);
bar();            // 'this' is 'object'
```

So you can see that the default is `window` when the function is invoked without any sort of connection to another object.

But when we call the  function as a property of an object, `this` suddenly refers to that object.

Or  we can use `.call`, `.apply` or `.bind` to manually set the `this` value of the function call.

Comment: if there's no object context, the this value becomes the default window. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a new closure, the meaning of `this` is lost. `this` has always been a tricky thing to deal with, so I prefer to always start such a function with `var that = this` to ensure that the meaning is not lost within closures.